# Update MediaItemDisplayProperties on the fly

Tags: stream, uwp, media-player

i have created a UWP App which uses HTML5 Webradio streams. 
Everything works fine but now i wanted to add track and artist information to the MediaPlayer Element. 
This information will be shown if the user locked his device, on the start screen. 
The first track if the user selects a stream is shown correctly. But I can't update this information without restart the Stream.

```
MediaItemDisplayProperties mdp = _mediaPlaybackItem.GetDisplayProperties();
mdp.Type = Windows.Media.MediaPlaybackType.Music;
mdp.MusicProperties.Artist = "TBA Artist";
mdp.MusicProperties.Title = "TBA Title";
mdp.Thumbnail = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(MainPage.Current.CurrentStream.PreviewImageUri);
_mediaPlaybackItem.ApplyDisplayProperties(mdp);
_mediaPlayer.Source = mpItem; 
_mediaPlayer.Play();
```

If i take this lines into my refresh Method for Artist/Title, I also have to set the Source of _mediaPlayer again which will result to a pause of playing the music.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem? Or give any advice I can look further.

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the Artist/Title, you should be able to use `System​Media​Transport​Controls​Display​Updater` class, it provides functionality to update the music information that is displayed on the SystemMediaTransportControls.

We can set Artist/Title to the `SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater.MusicProperties` property. Then we can use `SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater.Update` method to update the metadata for the currently playing media.

> Use the SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater class to update the media info that is displayed by the transport controls, such as the song title or the album art for the currently playing media item. Get an instance of this class with the SystemMediaTransportControls.DisplayUpdater property. If your scenario requires it, you can update the metadata displayed by the system media transport controls manually by setting the values of the MusicProperties, ImageProperties, or VideoProperties objects exposed by the DisplayUpdater class.

For example:

```
SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater updater = _systemMediaTransportControls.DisplayUpdater;    
updater.MusicProperties.Artist = "artist";
updater.MusicProperties.AlbumArtist = "album artist";
updater.MusicProperties.Title = "song title";    
updater.Thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Music/music1_AlbumArt.jpg"));    
updater.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. 

Only one correction. I had to set  updater.Type = MediaPlaybackType.Music because sometimes the media Element crashed. Music has played further, but no interaction on my locked device worked. (didn't see the MediaPlayer-element)